# How to rename part of the file name inside a folder using a for loop in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, renaming

I have a list of folders inside a directory. Each of these folders have files in them that needs to be processed but before that, I have to rename some of them. Here is my code so far.

```
for /D %%a in ("C:\locationOfFolders\*.*") do (
del %%a\*.gjf
del %%a\*.com
del %%a\*.chk
del %%a\*.xyz
del %%a\*o.log
ren %%a\*f1.log fragm1.log
ren %%a\*f2.log fragm2.log
```

So far, it deletes all the files ending with extensions .com,.gjf,...etc and renames files that end with f1 and f2. 
What I would like to do next is for files ending with "filenameof.log", I want to rename them to "filenamef.log". How do I go about doing this?

Comment: the examples i've seen are with set file names. but what if the file name is variable? eg. variablenameof.log <--- the variablename part changes.

Comment: [An advanced method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919938/batch-rename-multiple-files) or [a simplified method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763363/batch-file-rename-find-and-replace) (`ren "!name!" "!name:.of=.f!"`, suitable for names with one dot and without `!`).